# Add Checkbox to ListView Item in Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to add a `CheckBox` to every item in my `ListView`. I can't put a `CheckBox` widget in the `ListView`, so how do I do it? I think the Android settings has something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend a view adapter class and provide your own logic for creating the views for each row. Here's an [excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from an android development book at commonsware.com that might help.

Comment: I do have a SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, you should create an xml layout file representing an item in the ListView, in which you would declare a CheckBox. You can then set the adapter to use your layout for every item as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<T> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(this, R.layout.list_item, listReference); 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

setListAdapter is a method in ListActivity. Your list_item.xml should have the CheckBox defined in it.